# How to catch exceptions from .NETs Web API

Tags: .net, asp.net-web-api

i am returning exceptions from my webApi and would like to catch them accordingly.

the WebAPI code looks like this:

```
try
{
    _sessionProvider.Login(sessionId, user);
}
catch (UserLimitExceededException ex)
{
    return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, ex);
}
```

And when I call this webAPI using a .NET HttpClient I would like to catch this exception and identify  it properly.

How can I do this?

Comment: Is this code sample actually based inside the WebAPI controller method itself or is the consumer code?

Comment: This is my own WebAPI controller which I am communicating with

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to catch the response as an exception on the HttpClient. As far as HttpClient is concerned, it received a response from the WebAPI only that the status code is 500.

You will have to check for the status code in the response and act accordingly in the client side. Any other method to convert the response to a .Net exception on the client side is non-standard.

Answer (score 0):

Well, first off, the exception is not going to propagate to the client in the native .NET sense. There is no "magic" to make that happen.

When you call `CreateErrorResponse` it ends up creating an `HttpResponseMessage` whose status is 500 and whose content will be an [`HttpError`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.httperror(v=vs.118).aspx) instance which creates a representation of the exception on the wire. The `HttpError` will be serialized using whatever formatter has been selected by content negotiation so if, for example, the request was for type `application/json` the `HttpError` will be serialized into a JSON representation.

On the client side, if you're .NET, you would have to detect the 500 and then you can use `httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsAsync<HttpError>()` to deserialize it back into something structured that you can then read the details from.

Comment: Ok. I was hoping to deserialize the error exception automagically if I got a 500 back.